# Add multiple criteria in select

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause

I'm trying to complete my query with one additional criteria in select. This is how it looks now

```sql
SELECT
    c.hostname,
    s.executablepath,
    s.version,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 filesize
        FROM [inventorydatabase].[inv].[softwareview]
        WHERE version = s.version
          AND PathName = s.ExecutablePath
    ) AS 'Size'
FROM tblApplications ca
INNER JOIN tblSoftware s ON s.Software = cs.Software
INNER JOIN tblComputer c ON ca.CompID  = c.CompID
```

So this query gives me out result if I have match in both `version` tables and both `path` tables.

...but I need to add additional criteria so that it give me result of 'Size' even if I have only match in both `pathname = s.executablepath` tables.

Because there some applications with no version available and it just gives me `NULL` under `Size`.

Hope someone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please show us example source table data, and desired/expected output.

Comment: Why do you say "both version tables" and "both path tables"? Those are **columns**, not "tables".

Comment: yes, I`m sorry. You are correct - two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that *"there some applications with no version available"* means version is null, then the sub query would be:

```
select top (1) filesize
from [inventorydatabase].[inv].[softwareview]
where pathName = s.ExecutablePath and (
    version = s.version or
    version is null
)
```

Comment: Hi Salman A!
This looks good, but Im sorry that I didnt specify, but if there is no Version to the application, then its specified in tables as (n/a)

Comment: I guess `version = s.version or version = '(n/a)'` might do it. I am not a fan of storing strings like `n/a` in database.

Comment: Thank you! I think this will do the magic :)